# Laravel pass Eloquent Object from Job to another Job

Tags: laravel

I have the structure below. What I do is add some values that I need later on that are temporary and I don't want to store these in the database. But these values seem to be removed from the Eloquent Object once I pass it to another job. I think this has to do with the object being 'unserialized'?

**Job 1**

```
class JobOne implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $row;

    public function test()
    {
        $row = Model::findOrFail(5);

        $row['add_a_new_value'] = 'test';

        JobTwo::dispatch($row, 'something_else')->onQueue('queue_here');
    }
}
```

**Job 2**

```
class JobTwo implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $row;

    public function __construct($row)
    {
        $this->row = $row;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        dd($this->row); // This does not contain the 'add_a_new_value' key
        dd($this->row['add_a_new_value']); // This throws "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a model to a job, laravel keep only track of the model name and its ID.

To avoid that, add `SerializesModels;`

```php
class JobTwo implements ShouldQueue
{
    use SerializesModels;
    protected $row;
```

Or you can send a temporary variable to the job, just add another parameter to the constructor.

```php
class JobTwo implements ShouldQueue
{
    protected $row;
    protected $addNewValue;

    public function __construct($row, $addNewValue)
    {
        $this->row = $row;
        $this->addNewValue = $addNewValue;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        dd($this->addNewValue);
    }
}
```